# SVG backdrop-filter does not work correctly

Tags: html, svg, figma, backdrop

I made an SVG in Figma and I need the `backdrop-filter` to display correctly like in Figma.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDYJi.jpg)

```css
.main {
    stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.40);
    backdrop-filter: blur(25px);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="3398" height="4063" viewBox="0 0 3398 4063" fill="none" class="main">
    <g filter="url(#filter0_bddddi_108_20)">
    </g>
</svg>
```

I searched for a similar problem on the internet but couldn't find one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDYJi.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! _to display correctly like in Figma._ What does this mean? We don't know what you see in Figma. Edit your question to include an image, or at try to explain what isn't working correctly.

Comment: I don't see how the code you've posted would ever look anything like the images. Please post an [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.